# How to rearrange a Numpy array: 2D to 3D?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following array.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(100).reshape(20,5)
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
       [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
       [35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
       [40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
       [45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
       [50, 51, 52, 53, 54],
       [55, 56, 57, 58, 59],
       [60, 61, 62, 63, 64],
       [65, 66, 67, 68, 69],
       [70, 71, 72, 73, 74],
       [75, 76, 77, 78, 79],
       [80, 81, 82, 83, 84],
       [85, 86, 87, 88, 89],
       [90, 91, 92, 93, 94],
       [95, 96, 97, 98, 99]])
```

How do I reshape it to:

```
>>> a
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]],
       [[25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
        [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
        [35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
        [40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
        [45, 46, 47, 48, 49]],
       [[50, 51, 52, 53, 54],
        [55, 56, 57, 58, 59],
        [60, 61, 62, 63, 64],
        [65, 66, 67, 68, 69],
        [70, 71, 72, 73, 74]],
       [[75, 76, 77, 78, 79],
        [80, 81, 82, 83, 84],
        [85, 86, 87, 88, 89],
        [90, 91, 92, 93, 94],
        [95, 96, 97, 98, 99]]])
```

Comment: does `a.reshape(4,5,5)` do what you want?

Comment: The secondary matrices in the re-arranged example you provide contains 5, 6, 5, 4 rows respectively. Are you sure this is what you want? This is not a matrix any more.

Comment: @hpaulj My bad. Yes u r correct. I have corrected my typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to reshape is as @hpaulj mentioned in the comments:

```
a = a.reshape(4,5,5)
```